# regular expression for web site

Tags: jquery, regex

i am working with jquery and i was wondering what is the best regular expression for web site that will allow the following examples :

- http://www.google.com
- https://www.google.com
- www.google.com
- google.com

i was using this expression but its not working with all the examples .

```
[A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Answer (score 0):

Made this one for you:

```
(https?://)?(www\.)?google.com
```

You can test it here: http://regexpal.com/

Comment: google was just an exemple i need an expression for all websites

Comment: little ajustment: (https?://)?(www\.)?(.*)\.(.*)

Comment: You need to escape the `.` between the two `(.*)` capture groups.

Comment: and how about url that begin with http only not https

Comment: @user3882546 the `?` after the `s` means that there can be 0 or 1 occurrences of the character.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

UPDATED to include 'google.com'

```
^((ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/)?(([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-\._]+)+)|localhost)(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#_]*)?([\d\w\.\/\%\+\-\=\&amp;\?\:\\\&quot;\'\,\|\~\;]*)$
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to verify domains you could try this:

```
(\w{3,9}:\/\/)?([wW]\.)?([\w\d_%\-:=]+(\.|$|\b)){2,}
```